# Cannot import my selfsigned CA, it seems to not recognize the raw directory

Tags: android, ssl, self-signed

I'm trying to import my selfsigned CA in android so I can make HTTPS POST to a web server I selfsigned. Following Google Doc(https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html#ConfigCustom) I created directory res/raw/mycertificate and added my certificate in it. Created /res/xml directory and added the xml file network_security_config.xml to the manifest. It's in the network_security_config.xml file that I'm having some trouble, because when I create the tag  Android Studio get me an error on src telling me "Missing src resource" but I placed the certificate.pem in the directory /res/raw/mycertificate, and the folders raw and mycertificate does exists. How can I make Android Studio take correctly that path folder?

```
<network-security-config>
<domain-config>
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.1.200</domain>
    <trust-anchors>
          <certificates src="@raw/my_ca" />
    </trust-anchors>
</domain-config>
```

Comment: Hi benjamin did u resolve this one ? i am getting same issue

Comment: Yep same here, surprising a year gone by and no real answer.

Answer (score 12):

Omit the file extension for your certificate file in the network config XML file. If your cert is at `res/raw/my_cert.pem`, use this XML code:

```
<network-security-config>
<domain-config>
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.1.200</domain>
    <trust-anchors>
          <certificates src="@raw/my_cert" />
    </trust-anchors>
</domain-config>
```

Comment: i did a dumb thing. i put my cert in the right directory, but the wrong gradle module

Answer (score 6):

Actually, you must specify direct path to the certificate, not a directory path.

So, if you use `src="@raw/my_ca"`, file called my_ca.cer (or my_ca.der) must be placed inside resource folder.

Extract from documentation (https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html#certificates):

> - src
>
>   The source of CA certificates. Each certificate can be one of the following:
>
>   - a raw resource ID pointing to a file containing X.509 certificates. Certificates must be encoded in DER or PEM format. In the case of PEM certificates, the file must not contain extra non-PEM data such as comments.
>   - "system" for the pre-installed system CA certificates
>   - "user" for user-added CA certificates

Comment: I have same issue, it does nothing. Correct path. Certificate works fine, tested in non-android browsers and will even work if I import it to android under "user" trusted CAs. But this file in app load method gives blank page.

Comment: 4 years later... and it's STILL a problem. Valid cert, can load https local sites no problem, successfully added to both MacOS and android device AND emulator. But cannot build because the Android Studio Software (ASS) cannot find the bloody thing. I can open the cert and view it IN ANDROID STUDIO, but it cannot follow its own asinine pathing conventions to BUILD IT.

Comment: Seems that I encountered the same problem now and can't find a solution...

Answer (score 3):

I recently came across this problem. Eventually, I tried to build the project anyways and found out that the name of the file containing my self-signed CA had an uppercase letter. According to the build error I got, "File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore."